# struts2: param tag doesn't use conversion

Tags: tags, struts2, type-conversion

## Problem

In my struts2 application I have JSP page where the list of book is displayed. Each book has an id and the name. Also I want to place a link "edit" alongside any book, which can be edited by current user. This "edit" link should invoke corresponding action, passing book id as parameter to it. So I implemented this page using the code:

```
<table>
    <s:iterator value="books" status="stat">
        <tr>
            <td><s:property value="id"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="name"/></td>
            <td>
            <s:if test="canEdit[#stat.index]">
                <s:a action="editBook">edit
                    <s:param name="bookId" value="id"/>
                </s:a>
            </s:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

Book id is not of a basic type, I use custom class for it. So I decided to implement my own converter.
And here comes the problem: in the code above converter is used only when evaluating tag `<s:property value="id"/>` but it is not used to evaluate `<s:param name="bookId" value="id"/>`. Instead `toString()` method of book id class is used. Why `<s:param>` doesn't use my converter? How do i force it to do so? Or maybe there is another way to pass book id as parameter in link?

## Some (probably useless) details

To configure converter I placed `xwork-conversion.properties` inside my `/src/main/resources/` folder with the following contents:

```
my.app.Id = my.app.struts.IdConverter
```

`my.app.Id` is an abstract class which is extended by book id class.

The result of rendering of the JSP for a single-entry list is the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Book 01</td>
        <td><a href="/web/editBook.action?bookId=id%288%29">edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`id%288%29` is an escaped version of string `id(8)` which is the result of `toString()` method (defined in base abstract class `my.app.Id`) for id with int value of 8.

Answer (score 1):

The `<s:param>` tag is meant for "simple" parameters. In this case, you may be able to just set a temporary value using `<s:property>` if that does the conversion you expect.

It uses the `toString` of the book id because that's what a `getId()` will print out when rendered, just as if you did a `System.out.println(book.getId())`.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. But I still don't get the idea behind this. Both `param` and `property` are used to convert Object to String (param api docs explicitly point this). And the logic of this conversion is supposed to be controlled by me by means of converter. So I think at least this is not obvious that param tag is meant for "simple" parameters. What I'm missing here?

Comment: After some debugging of `org.apache.struts2.components.Property` and `org.apache.struts2.components.Param` I've found that the difference between them is that the first one uses `findValue(String,Class,boolean)` of ValueStack, while the second uses `findValue(String)` of base Component which eventually bring us to `findValue(String,boolean)` of ValueStack. The absense of `Class toClass` parameter (which is equal to `String.class` in case of property tag) will result in ignoring converter. So it seems that ignoring/using converter is a feature embedded in the framework. Even more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Found corresponding issue with explanation of problem:
http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/WW-808

In a few words the difference is between specifying `<param value="myValue"/>` and specifying `<param><property value="myValue"/></param>`. Conversion is used only in second case.